# What is Pablo Hidalgo reading?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In [*Rebels Recon* #3.11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NM7pTSxJKyY&index=1&list=PL148kCvXk8pBBJ1-qxpc_fdnlg0WiFWDS), Lucasfilm’s canon manager Pablo Hidalgo can be seen reading what looks like a *Star Wars* book with an orange cover.

[image]

Unfortunately, the resolution of the video and angle of the book is such that its title is hard to make out.

What is this book? Is there any relevance to what Hidalgo is talking about in the episode, or perhaps clues to future episodes of *Rebels*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book is **The Lost City of the Jedi** by Paul Davids, as part of the "*Star Wars Jedi Prince*" series.

The only word I could read was "Davids" so I searched for a star wars book by "Davids" and found the cover art:

[image: The Lost City of the Jedi]

This is a new cover, the cover on the book he is reading is the original cover:

[image: Original book series covers.]

Comment: Nice find! Does this give any clue to the future direction of *Rebels*?

Comment: I doubt it @Adamant, as the book series is part of Legends, and therefore contains a lot of assumptions about lore, etc.

Comment: True, but a *lot* of Legends material has been introduced into canon in one way or another. Maybe Pablo’s giving us a hint....

Comment: You're sure @Adamant about that... HAR!  HAR!  But seriously, I haven't read these books so I really can't answer that part.

Comment: Triclops confirmed for rebels?